# Protocol implementation in Swift without cast

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement a protocol that looks like this:

```
protocol CellDrawerProtocol {
    func cellFor(tableView: UITableView, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    func draw(cell: UITableViewCell, withItem anItem: ProfileItemProtocol)
}
```

The problem comes when i try to implement the protocol in some clases:

```
class TagCellDrawer : CellDrawerProtocol{

    internal func draw(cell: TagsTableViewCell, withItem anItem: Skills) {
        tagCell.configure(withSkills: skills)
    }

    internal func cellFor(tableView: UITableView, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tagsCell")!
    }

}
```

TagsTableViewCell inherits from UITableViewCell and Skills conforms to protocol ProfileItemProtocol but the compiler says that TagCellDrawer does not conform to protocol CellDrawerProtocol. So is there any way to avoid cast the classes inside the protocol implementation and use subclasses to implement the protocol.

Comment: Don't think this is possible, as you're not actually implementing the same function as is defined in the protocol (e.g. what if you have a different class which conforms to ProfileItemProtocol and call draw() with this as parameter?)

Comment: In Objective-C you can do it: http://pastebin.com/zS1Rarvm .

Comment: You can use an [associated type](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID189).